# When can an odd integer $d$ be represented as $d=a^2-2b^2$ with coprime integers $a,b\ $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples, representations-by-quadratic-forms

I found out that in a primitive pythagorean triple $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$ the difference $d=|a-b|$ (which must be odd) can occur, if and only if we can write $$d=a^2-2b^2$$ with positive coprime integers $a,b$. Moreover, $d$ is a possible difference if and only if $-d$ is a possible difference. We can replace the pair $(a/b)$ by $(a+2b/a+b)$ to get a solution of the desired form.

> When can an odd integer $d$ be written as $d=a^2-2b^2$ with positive coprime integers $a,b$ ?

The representation $49=9^2-2\cdot 4^2$ shows that $d$ need not be squarefree.

Comment: I know that this is a pell-type equation but I wonder how we can verify whether a coprime solution exists, this might be harder than to verify whether a solution exists at all.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/197918/) math overflow question answers your question.

Comment: When a is odd  then $d=a^2-2b^2$ is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are numbers that are not divisible by $4$ or by any prime $q \equiv 3,5 \pmod 8.$ You also are throwing out the single factor of $2$ that would otherwise be allowed.

```
   1 =  1 
   7 = 7
  17 = 17
  23 = 23
  31 = 31
  41 = 41
  47 = 47
  49 = 7^2
  71 = 71
  73 = 73
  79 = 79
  89 = 89
  97 = 97
 103 = 103
 113 = 113
 119 = 7 * 17
 127 = 127
 137 = 137
 151 = 151
 161 = 7 * 23
 167 = 167
 191 = 191
 193 = 193
 199 = 199
 217 = 7 * 31
 223 = 223
 233 = 233
 239 = 239
 241 = 241
 257 = 257
 263 = 263
 271 = 271
 281 = 281
 287 = 7 * 41
 289 = 17^2
 311 = 311
 313 = 313
 329 = 7 * 47
 337 = 337
 343 = 7^3
 353 = 353
 359 = 359
 367 = 367
 383 = 383
 391 = 17 * 23
 401 = 401
 409 = 409
 431 = 431
 433 = 433
 439 = 439
 449 = 449
 457 = 457
 463 = 463
 479 = 479
 487 = 487
 497 = 7 * 71
 503 = 503
 511 = 7 * 73
 521 = 521
 527 = 17 * 31
 529 = 23^2
 553 = 7 * 79
 569 = 569
 577 = 577
 593 = 593
 599 = 599
 601 = 601
 607 = 607
 617 = 617
 623 = 7 * 89
 631 = 631
 641 = 641
 647 = 647
 673 = 673
 679 = 7 * 97
 697 = 17 * 41
 713 = 23 * 31
 719 = 719
 721 = 7 * 103
 727 = 727
 743 = 743
 751 = 751
 761 = 761
 769 = 769
 791 = 7 * 113
 799 = 17 * 47
 809 = 809
 823 = 823
 833 = 7^2 * 17
 839 = 839
 857 = 857
 863 = 863
 881 = 881
 887 = 887
 889 = 7 * 127
 911 = 911
 919 = 919
 929 = 929
 937 = 937
 943 = 23 * 41
 953 = 953
 959 = 7 * 137
 961 = 31^2
 967 = 967
 977 = 977
 983 = 983
 991 = 991
```

Comment: I came to the same result, nevertheless, thank you. Since $d$ must be odd, we can even formulate it simpler : If $d>1$, then all prime factors of $d$ must be of the form $8k\pm 1$. This is also sufficient for the representation, so a pythagorean triple with such a $d$ will actually exist.